# Can't understand logic of code to find the sum of the evenly positioned digits

Tags: java, loops, bluej

So basically the question is something like:

> Write a program to accept a number from the user and find the sum of the evenly positioned digits counting from the left. For eg. if input is 94852 then output is 9(4+5).

Now, I am aware that this question can be done by converting the number to a string and using arrays, but in fact there is a better way of doing it.

The following program demonstrates the method -:

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(int a) {
        int evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0;
        int b = a; //b is used as a's value eventually becomes 0.
        while(a>0) { 
           int sum = evenSum + a % 10; 
           evenSum = oddSum; //Switching sums(?)
           oddSum = sum; //Interestingly,oddSum stores the sum of the oddly positioed digits
           a = a / 10; 
        }   
        System.out.println("The number entered is "+b);
        System.out.println("The even sum is " + evenSum);
    }
}
```

I happened to come across this answer when I was scouting for alternate solutions, and it left me stunned. I just couldn't understand the logic.

So can someone please explain what this method does and why it works?

Comment: you are just shifting the digits right with division and getting the right most digit with modulus

Comment: this question would fit better on the code review page.

Comment: Why don't you ditch `oddSum` and use `a /= 100;` instead? After initially divided by 10, of course.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, you want to *understand* the code. Sorry.

Comment: `oddSum` is important for different length of numbers

Comment: It saves the initial value of `a` into `b` so it can print it later, then uses `a` anyway?

Comment: @ScottHunter I suspect that is a bug in the code.

Comment: is this method meant to be the `main` method because if so the signature is wrong

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin: But you think there's a possibility that it isn't a bug?

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't see a way that it would not be a bug, but I don't see any other bugs in the code. It seems like something that would be immediately caught when testing, so it is too obvious to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code repeatedly shifts a digit to the right (integer division by 10). It picks the right most digit by modulo 10 (remainder of integer division).

It alternatively in the loop in one step sums in the one sum variable, in the next step in the other sum variable.

So one has two sums: of "odd" and "even" digits.

However as you name "odd" and "even" for positions from the *left*, and the loop starts from the *right*, you cannot say at the first step, first digit, wether that digit is at an odd or even position (counting from the left).

Hence you need to sum both odd and even positions.

And by swapping odd and even sums in every step, you ensure that always the momently last digit is added to the oddSum, evenSum indeed is the "even" sum.

Answer (score 0):

The code works because we use a decimal number system, in other words, each position in a number is 10 times as big as one to the right.

`a%10` is is taking the remainder of dividing by 10, and since all the numbers in all the positions other than the ones digit are divisible by 10, all you are left with is the ones digit.

`a = a/10` on the other hand is doing integer division (divide and drop the remainder) of the number meaning that you drop the ones digit of the number off of the end.

`evenSum` and `oddSum` The two sums are alternated so that the previous loop itterations sum is always stored in even sum and this iterations sum in oddSum. We know that the last iteration when the code completes is going to be on the left most digit (the first digit in your problem definition) and so is going to be the odd sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
Its a combination of maths & programming. I added a print statement after evenSum & this is the output what i got:

94852= a, 2 = a%10, 0 = evenSum,2 = sum in Step 1
9485= a, 5 = a%10, 2 = evenSum,5 = sum in Step 2
948= a, 8 = a%10, 5 = evenSum,10 = sum in Step 3
94= a, 4 = a%10, 10 = evenSum,9 = sum in Step 4
9= a, 9 = a%10, 9 = evenSum,19 = sum in Step 5
The number entered is 94852
The even sum is 9

2 rules are involved here:

1. Dividing a number by 10 leaves a decimal which gets omitted if variable declared as int.
2. Dividing a number by 10 leaves the remainder as the last digit if variable declared as int.

Rest all is self explanatory !
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic code to extract each digit of the number

```
while (a > 0) {
   int digit = a % 10;
   a /= 10;
}
```

The trick is to add each digit alternately to the even or odd sum

```
a = 0; b = 0; // these represent evenSum and oddSum
repeat
   take the last digit
   add the digit to b
   swap a and b // alternates
   remove the last digit
```

Adding the digit to b is done with a temporary variable 'sum'